# What is the meaning Marketing Review on Addons Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

Finally my module is pass "Technical review" on prestashop addons.

Now, i'm waiting for marketing review. I know that technical reviews are installition, php errors, coding standarts etc. But what is the meaning **Marketing Review** . It will take a long time?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About a week. Will control the pdf you attached, and all the descriptive fields you've entered in the control panel in the PrestaShop addons site